# May I use one certificate for a jetty server program that is distributed to hundred of users?

Tags: java, ssl, https, localhost, jetty

I hava a java app using jetty https server and I have a SSL certificate, I would like to know if there is some problems (technical or legal) that prevent me from distribute the app with the same certificate to some users.

Assume that the certificate is emitted for mysuperlocal.company.com. And in the hosts file of every cliente there will be an entry with:

```
127.0.0.1 mysuperlocal.company.com
```

What do you think about this? Keep in mind that the server is only for internal use in the computer of the user. The goal is communication between javascript code and that local server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on why you are doing this. Do you want some sort of security? Is it important that the local communication is secure but not important if the server is local? How will you install the certificate? Will users be able to export the private key? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me so maybe add some context of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I´m not worried about the private key, and about if the communication is truly secured, I only want the communication to be over SSL, because HTTPS web sites can´t acces HTTP service in anothers domains.

Comment: From a technical point of view there is no problem with this solution, except for the fact that it's a little bit... unusual. A web application normally sits on a server (or servers) somewhere and clients connect to it with their browsers. You instead have one web application for each client... whatever works for you it's OK I think. As for being some legal problems, I don't know, SO isn't the place to ask for legal advice.